# Regex to extract substring which contains PIPE (|)

Tags: regex

String1: `\txd\tbuba:pub|rub|spo-os|ix|beach|app|one|op|sono\tadT\tad\t`

String2: `\txd\tbuba:pub\tadT\tad\t`

I have two sample strings and need common regex to extract `pub|rub|spo|ix|beach|app|one|op|sono` and `pub`

I tried `buba:(\w(.)*(-os)?)\\t` but not working.

Please assist.

Comment: What regex tool or language are you using?

Comment: `buba:(\w+(?:\|[\w-]+)*)` and take the group 1 value https://regex101.com/r/zPeDvW/1 or `buba:(\w+(?:\|\w+(?:-os)?)*)\\t` https://regex101.com/r/tz5AV3/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, Thank you, it is working for me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
buba:(\w+(?:\|\w+(?:-os)?)*)\\t
```

**Explanation**

- `buba:` Match the string `buba:`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
  - `(?:\|\w+(?:-os)?)*` Optionally repeat `|` and 1+ word chars with optional `-os`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\\t` Match `\t`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tz5AV3/1)

The value is in capture group 1.

---

Or a broader variant

```
buba:(\w+(?:\|[\w-]+)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zPeDvW/1)

Comment: Hi
I have used 'buba:(\w+(?:\|\w+(?:-os)?)*)\\t' but it is not working for below string

\txd\tbuba:pub-os\tadT\tad\t
Expected output is 'pub-os'

Comment: @ManishSarafBhardwaj Try it like this https://regex101.com/r/V9ZPwd/1